# Join two tables in Yii via relations

Tags: php, join, yii

I am new to Yii framework. I have a task to list combined data of two tables with matching a key between two tables. I have the below table structure,

> **Log table**
>
> id,instance_id,user_id
>
> **Instance table**
>
> id,instance_id,instance_name

I have to show all the records from the 'Log table' in a CGridview. What I need is to display the instance_name also in that gridview.

How to set relation in these two models for achieving the result?

Comment: Relations are explained in all detail in the guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/385/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-hasmany-manymany-relations-in-cgridview/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two models called Log and Instance:

1. In Log.php add the method:

   public function relations()
   {
       return array(
           'instance' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Instance', 'instance_id'),
       );
   }
2. Add instance.instance_name to your CGridView widget.

   ```
   'columns'=>array(
   'id',
   'instance.instance_name',
    ...
   ```

...